# display address on google maps from database using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

I want to display addresses from database on google map using event click checkbox in javascript. I am unable to do so with  var url. How can I show the value(address) of the listings object? Appreciate your help. Thanks

HTML:

```
<div class="ellipsis">
    <a href="#"><p><b>{!! $listing->address !!}<br>{!! $listing->city !!}, {!! $listing->state !!} {!! $listing->postal !!}</b></p></a>
</div>
```

The JavaScript is as follows:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmaps-markers'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: {lat: 37.533333, lng: -77.466667}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        //sample markers, but you can pass actual marker data as function parameter
         document.getElementById('checkbox1').addEventListener('click', function() {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmaps-markers'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: {lat: 37.533333, lng: -77.466667}
        });

           if($(this).is(":checked"))
           {
              geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
            }
          else
            {
                map.setMap(null);
            }
        });

         function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {

        var url = '<?php echo $listing ;?>';
        var request = {address: url};
        console.log(request);
        geocoder.geocode(request, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: resultsMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

     return map;
```